# Object Policy instead of Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-s3

Using amazon s3.

I have a structure like;

```
bucket
  ./folder1
    ./sub1(xxx.com)
      1.png
      2.png
    ./sub2(yyy.com)
      1.png
  ./folder2
    ./sub1(xxx.com)
      1.png
    ./sub2(ttt.com)
      1.png
```

I may set bucket policy for those folders. eg: sub folders need referer statements and folder1 and folder2 needs allow or deny. Everything works fine.

But I'm afraid I don't have only 2 main and 3 sub folders.

Aprox I will have nearly 100 folders and nearly 250 sub folders for each of them. And also If possible I want to make access control file by file (referer based). So I have to set a bucket policy with minimum 25.000 statement line.

If I tried to generate policy for those folders and files, It would be too big for a policy file and I'm not sure that they will work properly and fastly. And the worser situation is, It has to be set every minute or so (depends on users activity on their management panel).

I'm searching for object or folder based policy but I couldn't find anything like that.

And searched for transactional policy or something (like adding rules to policy, one by one). And couldn't find anything.

On the other hand, I may create buckets for main folders. Buckets up limit is 100. Even there are too many folders for that. And still needs to generate 250 statement or something like that.

Are there any method or suggestion out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to apply same policy on all object or different, if same then I think you do not need to add rule for each folder/sub folder. But of you want to apply different for each folder then you have to apply for each folder/sub folder. Can you explain more about your problem ?

Comment: @TejKiran I want to apply different rules for different folders. first of all, all sub folders gonna restrict with their name based referers. like stackoverflow.com folder or xxx.com folder.

and every main folder is gonna allow or deny based on their pre paid credits.